# Faulting CLR.dll on Framework 4.5.2

Tags: .net

I still have problem with faulting module clr.dll, which cause application crash when customer use device...

We used Framework version 4.0 and found out this problem, so we upgraded OS from windows 7 to windows 8 and Framework from 4.0 to 4.5.2. Problem still continue...

```
*Information from Eventviewer:
*Faulting application name: Mikro.FareOn.Modules.Cards.Client.KioskJihlava.exe, version: 3.0.804.3406, time stamp: 0x56cb21bd
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18408, time stamp: 0x52310b2d
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0047cb35
Faulting process id: 0xba4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d29eef3c327226
Faulting application path: c:\mikroelektronika\kiosk\Mikro.FareOn.Modules.Cards.Client.KioskJihlava.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: b9419dac-0aed-11e7-a037-00045f8f3145
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:*

*Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: BEX
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: Mikro.FareOn.Modules.Cards.Client.KioskJihlava.exe
P2: 3.0.804.3406
P3: 56cb21bd
P4: clr.dll
P5: 4.0.30319.18408
P6: 52310b2d
P7: 0047cb35
P8: c0000409
P9: 00000002
P10: 
Attached files:
These files may be available here:
C:\Users\kiosk1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_Mikro.FareOn.Mod_91f327b9c548e7d593481687d6a18516e131862d_091355f6
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b9419dac-0aed-11e7-a037-00045f8f3145
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket:*
```

I have installed .Net Framework 4.5.2

[image]

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: It is your application who crashes and CLR.dll raises the exception, not that library itself crashes. Learn how to Debug and locate the culprit in your code.

Comment: How did you get that NetFXVersion output?

Answer (score 1):

The Exception code `0xc0000409` indicates a STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN. ntstatus.h says:

```
The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in
this application.  This
overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain
control of this application.
```

Since clr checks buffer sizes, I guess there is something wrong with unchecked or native code in your app.

If this happens only on your customers PC, it may be that there are other apps installed on the customer PC, that probably do DLL injection and cause problems. I know of antivirus tools and spellchecker / translator apps that use such techniques.